# RQR12.10_B0032 device update fails

Tags: updates

I don't have a wired keyboard or mouse.  After attempted install, I had to reboot 18.04 in recovery mode.  I don't need this update on home machine anyway.  I'd update it if it would succeed, however it keeps popping up for update request.  I prefer not to turn off ALL update requests, just this one, ...so far.  Has anyone else encountered this?  Solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This update is for the Logitech Unifying wireless dongle. As such, you should not move the mouse/keyboard during the update, or the update will fail.

The system *may* require a reboot, or a re-plug of the dongle, after the update.

**Note**: If need be, if you have Windows, use the `Logitech Unifying Software` to update the firmware in the Logitech Unifying wireless dongle.

Comment: I tried reinstalling it and no attempt was made.  I got an error msg. 
""Unable to update "Unifying Receiver (RQR12) Device Update":  failed to detach to bootloader: failed to send: failed to write: wrote -1 of 7""
At this point I had no input device, Rebooting did not restore it, so I disconnected dongle for kb/mouse and got them back.

Comment: @EugeneConway There are a number of different Logitech Unifying dongles. Since you probably have two of these... one that came with the mouse, and one that came with the keyboard... try the other dongle.

Comment: Only one dongle, keyboard and mouse came as a set.

Comment: If you have Windows, use the `Logitech Unifying Software` to reset the dongle. Otherwise use `Solaar` in Ubuntu. Prefer Windows, if you have it. Then either update the firmware from Windows, or retry in Ubuntu. You can also temporarily take the dongle/mouse/keyboard to another Windows machine to set it up.

Comment: @EugeneConway Any luck?

Comment: I won't know until the reminder pops up tomorrow.  And I've got other things to do right now.  Thanx

Comment: @EugeneConway Please give me more details. Did you update the firmware from Windows, or did you get it to finally go in Ubuntu?

Comment: I got it going in Ubuntu.  I can apparently get the system to recognize the input devices by unplugging and replugging the dongle, without having to reboot.